# Who should I share my writing ideas with

Tags: structure, ideas

- I'm too scared to share with my family
- My online friends only know of *Star Wars*

  - I got an idea stolen
  - I don't really know anyone in real life

I would like to know if there is a way to contact anyone on here one to one like a Direct message. I haven't found out how. I need to share my ideas with someone because I am now not feeling confident, and I found out an already made story is like mine.

Comment: You might try Critique Circle. http://www.critiquecircle.com/

Comment: Don't be afraid of anyone "stealing" your idea or "stealing" ideas yourself. Every good idea gets stolen. The most famous stories in world history consist mostly of ideas which were taken from other people's stories and recombined in new and interesting ways.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how far you have gotten already in writing your ideas down, but there are many online communities where you can upload your ideas and/or stories and ask for feedback. As one user above said, any good idea will get stolen eventually. On the other hand everyone does (intentionally or not) copy from other people's works and techniques. Even the words we use have been invented by others. If you are afraid of sharing your ideas, you won't be able to get any feedback. Anyways, great communities where you could ask for feedback are absolutewrite.com/forums, archiveofourown.org (fanfic), [reddit.com/r/DestructiveReaders](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestructiveReaders/), [noveltrove.com](https://noveltrove.com) (erotic fiction) and many, many more...

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably going to get a gazillion negatives for this but why would you want to share your writing ideas?

99% of writers fail to write anything of significance. Writers fall into two categories: (1) hobbyists. These people want to discuss their imaginary worlds with others who have also constructed their own alternative worlds which they can retreat into. (2) Professional writers: these people earn their living; ghost-writing, script-writing, speech-writing. This is what they do feed their families. Why would they want to help you eat into their slice of pie?

Personally, I've got 100 plots that are all good that'll take time to convert to stories - time that I'll never get back.

Real, established writers are a select group. Stories are not their 'babies'. They'll sit outside cafes drinking coffee. One will say they've got an idea for a story about a female US Muslim president. The others will tell the writer, "That'll never fly."
And they'll move on to the next idea.

Your idea that you want to share is not that special - trust me on that.

Comment: It might not be famous. All of my ideas could be flops. I still have hope that I could reach any where as a shelf on a bookstore.

Comment: Bit confused by this answer. Your scenario in the fourth paragraph is surely the exact reason anyone would want to share their ideas: to get feedback. Which is what the OP seems to be looking for.

Comment: Your philosophy is part wrong. It isn't not you who choose the success of an idea. Let's take hunger games for instance. If You were to say this to her before she wrote the book, you would be wrong.

Comment: And from what I've seen. The world needs ideas. They are only bringing back the old stuff, Lemony Snicket TV show, and Anne of green gables. I think we re ready for the next generation writers to form.

Comment: @A.N.M _The Hunger Game_ was not a new idea. It is simply a distaff Spartacus. There have been a thousand gladiatorial games stories, with every possible riff on the idea being explored. Kirk vs. the Gorn, for instance. Girl gladiators is an old B movie trope. It is never the idea. It is always the execution.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you want to share story ideas, and not written work. You just want to bounce ideas around with friends. That's a great idea.

Gather a group of literate friends. I doubt they only know about Star Wars. They know about human relationships, right? And drama and love and humor? Start with those friends. Take a class at your arts center or community college. You'll meet more people there. Go to readings in your area. Look for them at bookstores and colleges. If your city has a literary organization, go to their events. In other words, hang out with writers. I think it's important to have writing friends in the real world.

Eventually you might find opportunities to join a writing group - or create one.

You say you're not feeling confident. We all understand that. But the way to get through it is to just keep writing. Just write your story.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same situation... mostly I have a bunch of friends I retreat to when I need help editing something or when I want opinions.

I agree with both the answers above. This has happened with me and other people I know. While writing fanfictions, many of our plot ideas were stolen. Now since we just wrote for fun or for the joy it presents, it was an added advantage to see our fav characters live the situations that we envisioned them to live in. However, for a serious person who wants to pursue this as career, this is the most horrible thing that can happen.

If you want to share ideas and have people give their advice or read other people's ideas, there are two things based on how secure your work shall remain -

1. have a bunch of friends who share similar interests and are willing to help. You know they will be honest and there will be no threat for work stealth.
2. join a fanfiction forum or portal where you can share your work.